# ReactJS button onClick suddenly stopped working

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Some of my buttons onClick has stopped working, and I'm getting `Expected onClick listener to be a function, instead got a value of object type.`
Some onClick's working flawlessly, but onClick in child components has stopped work. I tried every solution and nothing work (maybe I'm doing something wrong in the process). Please help.

**App.js**

```
function App() {

  useEffect(() => {
    apiTest()
  })

  const currentModulee = currentModule((state) => state.data)
  

  return (
  <>
      <NavBr />
      <InfoToast/>
      <Container className="pt-3">
        {currentModulee}
      </Container>
  </>
  );
}
```

**Component with problems:**

```
import React from 'react'
import { noteNames } from "./Storage"
import { Nav } from "react-bootstrap"
import { noteOptionsIdChange } from './Storage'


export default function SettingsA() {
    const a = noteNames((state) => state)

    if (typeof(a) != "undefined") {
        return (
            <>
            {Object.values(a).map((name, index) => {return <Nav.Link key={index} onClick={() => noteOptionsIdChange(index)}>{name}</Nav.Link>})}
            </>)
        }}
```

onClick from above doesn't work, some time ago there was no problem.

**Working Navigation Bar:**

```
export default function NavBr() {
  const statusConn = statusCon((state) => state.data);

  return (
    <Navbar bg="light" expand="lg">
      <Container fluid>
        <Image alt="" src={AnkiLogo} width="30" height="30" className='me-1 ms-5'/>
        <Navbar.Brand href="#home" onClick={() => {moduleChange("");}}>MIA DB</Navbar.Brand>
        <Navbar.Collapse id="basic-navbar-nav">
          <Nav className="me-auto">
            <Nav.Link onClick={() => moduleChange("recalc")}><ArrowClockwise /> Recalc</Nav.Link>
            <Nav.Link onClick={() => moduleChange("import")}><FileArrowUp /> Import</Nav.Link>
            <Nav.Link onClick={() => moduleChange("export")}><FileArrowDown /> Export</Nav.Link>
            <Nav.Link onClick={() => moduleChange("util")}><Tools /> Utility</Nav.Link>
            <Nav.Link onClick={() => moduleChange("browse")}><BoxSeam /> Browse</Nav.Link>
            <Nav.Link onClick={() => moduleChange("ust")}><Gear /> Ustawienia</Nav.Link>
            <Nav.Link onClick={() => {moduleChange("stat"); makeRequest('GET', 'stats', statsChange, null, false)}}><FileBarGraph /> Statystyki</Nav.Link>
          </Nav>
        </Navbar.Collapse>
        <Button className='float-end me-4' variant='primary' onClick={() => window.location.reload(false)}>Refresh</Button>
        <OverlayTrigger placement='bottom' overlay={<Tooltip>Status połączenia z API</Tooltip>}>
          <Button className='float-end me-4' variant={statusConn}>Status</Button>
        </OverlayTrigger>
      </Container>
    </Navbar>
  );
};
```

Above onClick's working as usual, no problem with them at all.

**Storage.js - function executed onClick**

```
export function noteOptionsIdChange(val) {
    noteOptionsId.setState(val)
    makeRequest("GET", `note_options/${val}`, noteOptionsFinChange)
    console.log(val, "noteOptionsIdChange")
}
```

Tried to do something with webpack but at my newbie eye it's not it, used many variations of invoking onClick event like changing function, passing props etc.
Tested functions if they are working properly, I did 'raw run' on component render above return statement and everything is good (producing expected result).

EDIT
When I changed onClick to onClickCapture/onDoubleClick error still occurs but function executes as it should
[image]

When I'm changing it to onMouseEnter/onMouseLeave/onMouseOver error not occurring and everything is okay.

Interesting fact:
A button without onClick assigned still produces error when clicked.

Comment: Did you try to `console.log()` inside the onClick handler?

Comment: Console log from NavBar gave me sucessful print to the console but when I did it from not working button (SettingsA) it gave me same result as usual which is `Uncaught Error: Expected onClick listener to be a function, instead got a value of object type.`

Comment: Please post the full code for the file you describe as "component with problems". The snippet that you posted does not include `noteOptionsIdChange` so we can't see what that is or how you are accessing it.

Comment: Also, your useEffect is missing a dependency array. And where do `currentModule` and `noteNames` get state from? There seems to be a lot of variables accessed from closures, which can yield unexpected results.